# jquery tear paper advertising

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want **tear paper** script like as [MGM Grand Hotel Website](http://www.mgmgrand.com/) at the corner advertising, but no need flash animation. I want in jquery or any ideas.

How to call that effect?

Comment: Yes ...it is ... idea is very simple just do some coding ... now what i want to say that is  please try first than if you got any problem than ask here. Your question doesn't show any efforts

Comment: Yes sure I tried. i need some plug-ing to save my time. free or pay script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of choices - http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-page-peel-plugins/

Not really a good question for stackoverflow. A quick google would have yielded these possibilities for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to search with "tear paper effect" some things like that, but not found. I don't know exactly the name of this effect.